# How best to query a many-to-many relationship for "all Y for each X that has a matching Y"

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

I have a table, two columns, `user` and `group`. It's a many-to-many relationship, so we might have...

```
group |  user
1     |  1
1     |  2
1     |  3
2     |  1
2     |  3
3     |  1
3     |  4
4     |  2
4     |  3
```

... and so on.

I need to get a list of users in all the groups which contain a particular a user ID. So for the above, if I gave it user ID 3, it would first get all the groups for that (in this case, 1, 2, and 4), and then return all the users for those groups (in this case, 1, 2, and 3). Right now, this is accomplished through two nested selects:

```
SELECT * FROM other_table
WHERE user_id IN (
    SELECT user_id FROM table WHERE group_id IN (
        SELECT group_id FROM table WHERE user_id = 3
    )
)
```

This is proving horribly inefficient. Is there something obvious I'm missing here?

Even if I run the query on its own, it runs very inefficiently:

```
SELECT user_id FROM table WHERE group_id IN (
    SELECT group_id FROM table WHERE user_id = 3
)
```

Edit: Here's the `CREATE TABLE` for the table.

```
CREATE TABLE `user_groups` (
  `user_id` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `group_id` bigint(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`,`group_id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Edit: And the explain of what happens with the query in the answer below:

```
id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys            | key      | key_len | ref         | rows | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      | t1    | ref    | PRIMARY,user_id,group_id | PRIMARY  | 8       | const       | 839  | Using index
1  | SIMPLE      | t2    | ref    | PRIMARY,user_id,group_id | group_id | 8       | t1.group_id | 2331 | 
1  | SIMPLE      | users | eq_ref | PRIMARY                  | PRIMARY  | 8       | t2.user_id  | 1    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a self-join:

```
SELECT other_table.*
FROM   `table` t1
  JOIN `table` t2 USING (group_id)
  JOIN other_table ON other_table.user_id = t2.user_id
WHERE  t1.user_id = 3
```

Comment: Makes sense but still way too slow... this table has 2.2 million rows and all of the solutions take over half a minute.

Comment: @Andrew: Do you have indexes on both `group_id` and `user_id`?

Comment: `user_id` and `group_id` are the primary key, and there's individual indexes on both columns. I just added another index, for fun, on `group_id` and `user_id` to no improvement.

Comment: @Andrew: And is there an index on `other_table.user_id`?  Can you post `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output for both tables, together with the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` for my query above?

Comment: Added the create table for the table in question. The other table does have an index on `user_id`, thats its primary key in fact.

Comment: @Andrew: And also the `EXPLAIN` output, please?

Comment: I may have found a way around it - if I run the query on its own, with the tips you gave for joining, it takes a second, and if I throw the results of that into the IN() clause in the other query, rather than having a subquery in that IN(), then it runs in only 3 seconds, a vast improvement. I've added the EXPLAIN above though, just in case that helps solve the more immediate issue.

Comment: Spoke too soon - didn't realize `group_concat_max_len` was set to 1k, which artificially smallened the results. Crud.

Comment: @Andrew: How many users are we dealing with here, relative to the total size of the relevant groups? `SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT u2.user_id) FROM user_groups u1 JOIN user_groups u2 USING (group_id) WHERE u1.user_id = 3`

Comment: COUNT(*) of 2205310, COUNT(DISTINCT) of 27508. is it simply going to be that this is too large to get a speedy query from?

Comment: I seem to have found an actual way around it - Using a temporary memory table. That way, the self-join is much much faster, and it returns in 5 seconds what used to take 28 seconds.

Comment: Oy, also turns out much of the time may have been in the transit rather than the selection. Giving you the checkbox because you did help, and I will use your join later, but I may have been off on the cause the whole time.